# .htaccess как убрать index.html из URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess как убрать index.html из URL 
к примеру имеем
http://flying-p-liners.com/uslugi/ofisnyj-pereezd/index.html
а надо 
http://flying-p-liners.com/uslugi/ofisnyj-pereezd/

пробовал вот так

```
RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.html$ [http://www.имя](http://www.%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F) сайта.ru/ [R=301,L]

нечего не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Первое что найдет сервер при запросе https://your-url/something/, например, то и будет отдано в ответ